# Parsing Placeholders as SQL Arguements PHP

Tags: php, sql, parsing

I am trying to find a good way of paring sql arguements, the way I am accomplishing it now seems like it can use a lot of improvement. I am trying to convert arguements that are split apart by ', & <= =>' from a string into SQL arguements like name = 'ABC' OR name ='John Doe'.

So

```
parseSQLOperators('dan,john&steven', 'username');
```

Will create

```
WHERE username= 'dan' OR username = 'john' AND username ='steven'
```

I have an example how this is being accomplished below but I am wondering if there is a better way for this.

```
public static function parseSQLOperators($string, $content_term, $encapsulate = TRUE) {

        $string = trim($string);
        $length = strlen($string);

        $ADD_PREFIX = true;
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

            if ($string[$i] == '!') {

                $output .= ' ' . $content_term . '!=\'';

                if ($i == 0) {
                    $ADD_PREFIX = false;
                }
            } else if ($string[$i] == '+') {
                if (@$string[$i + 1] != '!') {
                    $output .= ' AND ' . $content_term . '=\'';
                } else {
                    $output .= ' AND ';
                }
            } else if ($string[$i] == ',') {
                if (@$string[$i + 1] != '!') {
                    $output .= ' OR ' . $content_term . '=\'';

                } else {
                    $output .= ' OR ';
                }

            }

            if ($string[$i] != '!' && $string[$i] != '+' && $string[$i] != ',') {

                $output .= $string[$i];

                if (@$string[$i + 1] == ',' || @$string[$i + 1] == '+' || @$string[$i + 1] == '!' || $i == $length || $i == $length - 1) {
                    $output .= '\'';
                }
            }
        }//end for

        if ($ADD_PREFIX == true) {
            $output = $content_term . '=\'' . $output;
        }

        if ($encapsulate) {
            $output = '(' . $output . ')';
        }

        return $output;
    }//end parseSQLOperator
```

Comment: You should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing `$string[$i]` 's value, you could use a switch / case statement, like this:

```
   switch ($string[$i])
   {

       case '!':

            $output .= ' ' . $content_term . '!=\'';

            if ($i == 0) {
                $ADD_PREFIX = false;
       break;

       case '+':
            if (@$string[$i + 1] != '!') {
                $output .= ' AND ' . $content_term . '=\'';
            } else {
                $output .= ' AND ';
            }
       break;

       case ',':
            if (@$string[$i + 1] != '!') {
                $output .= ' OR ' . $content_term . '=\'';

            } else {
                $output .= ' OR ';
            }

        }

      default:
            $output .= $string[$i];
            if (@$string[$i + 1] == ',' || @$string[$i + 1] == '+' || @$string[$i + 1] == '!' || $i == $length || $i == $length - 1) {
                $output .= '\'';
            }
    }
```